# Changing only one property of font globally for all tikz pictures but keeping other locally set properties of font

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, color

I am writing a thesis with many plots. I would like to be able to change one property for all plots globally. In my example I try to change the size of the font of the ylabels of all plots, but I would like to keep all other locally set properties, like for example the color of the ylabels.
I tried the following with no success:

```
\documentclass[12pt, rgb, german,table]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric,plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,external}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{every axis/.append style={ylabel style={font={\small \sffamily}},tick label style={font=\scriptsize \sffamily}}}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includestandalone{Fit}%     without .tex extension
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the tikz file example is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=5 cm,
        height= 5 cm ,
        at={(6.5 cm, 0cm)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=7,
        xlabel={},
        xmajorticks=false,
        separate axis lines,
        axis y line*=right,
        every outer y axis line/.append style={mycolor2},
        every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
        every y tick/.append style={mycolor2},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel/.append style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
        ylabel={$A$ (pixel)},
        axis background/.style={fill=none},
        yticklabel pos=right,
        clip marker paths=true, 
        axis on top=true,
        ]
        \addplot [color=mycolor2, only marks, mark=*, mark options={solid, mycolor2}, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
            1   1.15960009643026\\
            2   2.41853566710355\\
            3   3.6107259394201\\
            4   4.82171231418267\\
            5   6.04375717648504\\
            6   7.23340089514461\\
        };
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This changes the font size of the ylabels to small, but changes also the color of the ylabels to black, but I would like them to keep the color I set in the `TikZ` file.

Comment: With `{ something }` in brackets, you can create a scope. If you change some value within the brackets, it is reverted as soon as the compiler leaves the brackets.

Comment: It always helps, if you add, what you get as output and what you want instead (ms paint does the job).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All common styles for all pictures you can define in `\pgfplotsset`. For example, a MWE where are locally set different colors for more easy to see effect of global and local settings. in it is simplified way of setings too:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18,
             ylabel style={font=\small\sffamily},
             tick label style={font=\scriptsize \sffamily}
             }
```

All this settings you can overwrite locally. So to this settings you can add others, which are used in the most of pictures (for example picture size, axis style etc. and at exception locally overwrite them.

An example for global and local settings for `pgfplots` diagrams:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{tikz} % is loaded by `pgfplots`
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18,
             ylabel style={font=\small\sffamily},
             tick label style = {font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                                 /pgf/number format/use comma},
             }

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                plotmarks}
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=5 cm, height= 5cm ,
        at={(6.5 cm, 0cm)},  % ?, at standalone this has no sense
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=7, xlabel={},
        xmajorticks=false,
        separate axis lines,
        axis y line*=right,
        y axis line style={mycolor2},
        y tick label style={mycolor2},
        y tick style=blue,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        ylabel style={mycolor2},
        ylabel={$A$ (pixel)},
        %axis background style={fill=none},
        yticklabel pos=right,
        clip marker paths=true,
        axis on top=true,
        ]
        \addplot [color=mycolor2, only marks, mark=*, mark options={solid, mycolor2}, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
            1   1.15960009643026\\
            2   2.41853566710355\\
            3   3.6107259394201\\
            4   4.82171231418267\\
            5   6.04375717648504\\
            6   7.23340089514461\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=5 cm, height= 5cm ,
        at={(6.5 cm, 0cm)},  % ?, at standalone this has no sense
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=7, xlabel={},
        xmajorticks=false,
        separate axis lines,
        axis y line*=right,
        y axis line style={green},
        y tick label style={blue},
        y tick style={mycolor2},
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        ylabel style={mycolor2},
        ylabel={$A$ (pixel)},
        axis background style={fill=none},
        yticklabel pos=right,
        clip marker paths=true,
        axis on top=true,
        ]
        \addplot [color=mycolor2, only marks, mark=*, mark options={solid, mycolor2}, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
            1   1.15960009643026\\
            2   2.41853566710355\\
            3   3.6107259394201\\
            4   4.82171231418267\\
            5   6.04375717648504\\
            6   7.23340089514461\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={ylabel/.append style={font={\small \sffamily}},tick label style={font=\scriptsize \sffamily}}}` in your main document.

[image]